# Java Optimizing private methods

Tags: java, performance, oop, memory, static

I have a Java application with a service class that has numerous (around 20 or so) private methods. I've been doing a lot of reading about private vs private static methods. I want to optimize the runtime efficiency of this service class and was wondering what are the performance/memory/etc differences between the following methods:

```
private foo() {}
private final foo() {}
private static foo() {}
private final static foo() {}
```

I've been reading [this article](http://dicky-programmingjoy.blogspot.com/2007/04/why-use-private-static-method.html) and [this stack software engineering post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234412/why-have-private-static-methods) to get an understanding but I still don't have a complete grasp.

Comment: All else being equal, none.

Comment: The differences are not worth paying any attention to.  I'm completely and utterly serious.  Any "optimizations" you could make will get done for you automatically, so just write the code that's clearest.

Comment: If the method doesn't need access to instance fields and/or instance methods, make the method `static`, to document the fact that it is not using instance values. There is no good reason for making private methods `final`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize code to be more efficient then you need first find out where are the biggest bottlenecks. Improvements in these identified areas will have the biggest payoff.

Don't be tempted discussing optimization of code that has not been been written yet.